# write() is adding padding when my strings are 4-5 characters?

Tags: c, sockets

The following write() is received by the client correctly:

```
char *foo = "ABC";
write(sock, foo, strlen(foo));
```

But when I extend the foo string to 4 or 5 characters, write() will pad the string with garbage until it has 6 characters.  Example of a write that gets extra padding:

```
char *foo = "ABCD";
write(sock, foo, strlen(foo));
```

Anybody know why this happens?

Comment: How exactly did you come up with this conclusion ? What does the client code look like ?

Comment: The code is correct and should write "ABC" in the first example and "ABCD" in the second example. The problem could be that you don't send the trailing \0 along with the letters so that you misinterpret what is sent. Replace strlen(foo) with strlen(foo)+1.

Comment: How does the client know how many bytes to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect as apparently all the others, that you are reading the characters on the other side of the connection and printing them with `printf()` which expects a `nul` terminated sequence of bytes, i.e. a string, so either write the `nul` byte like this

```
write(sock, foo, 1 + strlen(foo));
```

or where you recieve it, do it like this

```
int count;
char array[LARGER_THAN_POSSIBLE_COUNT];
count = read(sock, array, sizeof(array));
if (count > 0)
    fwrite(array, 1, count, stdout);
fprintf(stdout, "\n");
```

Comment: The "1 + strlen(foo)" worked but I'm not sure why it isn't required for strings less than 4 characters.

Comment: @ChrisSong because passing a non `nul` terminated string to `fprintf()` causes undefined behavior, so it might work, or it may fail, it's undefined.